# Who is an “Adhishtathri”?

Tags: shiva, tantra, parvati, maya, iskcon

I have heard that Lord Shiva made Mother Parvati the “adhishtathri” of tantra sidhdhi.

I have also heard ISKCON Acharyas saying that Mother Parvati is the “adhistathri” of maya.

I would like an answer that verifies these two claims,with proof,along with explanation for the word “adhishtatri”
Thank you.

Comment: Adhisthatri means Presiding deity...

Comment: @Tezz Thank you